# AES Encryption SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I received this from a cold fusion developer.

```
<cfset mySearchCriteria = encrypt("empid_10112","KeyCrypt","AES",”Hex”)>
```

In SQL server, I tried this code:

```
select emp_id, ENCRYPTBYKEY(key_guid('KeyCrypt'),emp_id) as encrypt_empid from table1
```

But this returns nulls in the encrypt_empid column. How to encrypt a column based on the encryption key provided by the cold fusion team? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[ENCRYPTBYKEY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/encryptbykey-transact-sql)

> Returns NULL if the key is not open, if the key does not exist, or if the key is a deprecated RC4 key and the database is not in compatibility level 110 or higher.

so you may need to open key prior to using it..here is one example from DOCS..

```
OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY SSN_Key_01  
   DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE HumanResources037; 
UPDATE HumanResources.Employee  
SET EncryptedNationalIDNumber  
    = EncryptByKey(Key_GUID('SSN_Key_01'), NationalIDNumber);
```